# SignInManager.SignInAsync doesn't sign me in (Vue.js SPA)

Tags: c#, vue.js, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

I'm having some odd problems with authentication on an app which consists of a dotnet core 2.1 API back end and a Vue.js SPA front end.

I've got all of the key elements and layers in place for logging in and logging out on the back end using an Auth API controller and I've got a basic login page on the Vue app with which I can log in.

The front end app consists of 3 key pages at the moment 'Landing' (with a click here to log in line on it), 'Home' for logged in users and the Log In page itself.

If I log in then the log in API call returns my basic user data and roles, so I store that in Vuex state and use it to load the home page. However, if I try to go back to the landing page by refreshing the page back to the root URL then the Vue app should trigger a routine that will assess the user status and adapt accordingly (It does this first by checking Vuex state and, if empty, it then calls the auth controller to get the User and role data and repopulate itself) so, as I've logged in, I should be redirected back to the logged in 'Home' page. This doesn't happen - Instead, the 'Landing' (Not logged in) page is shown.

I've got some general logging that trickles through and I've added some more as I've gone and it's clear that when I make the second call I am, for some reason, no longer authorised although I cannot for the life of me figure out why.

I've used this set up before very successfully - the only difference is that the dev API backend is ASP.Net Core and not .net Framework.

I'm open to any ideas of where to start looking at this?

Here's my Startup config...

```
       public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory,
        ApplicationDbContext context, RoleManager<IdentityRole> roleManager, UserManager<ApplicationUser> userManager)
    {
        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app
                .UseDeveloperExceptionPage()
                .UseDatabaseErrorPage();
        }
        else
        {
            app
                .UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error")
                .UseHsts();
        }

        app
            .UseAuthentication()
            .UseHttpsRedirection()
            .UseStaticFiles()
            .UseSpaStaticFiles();

        app.UseMvc(routes =>
            {
                routes.MapRoute(
                    name: "default",
                    template: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
            });

        app.UseSpa(spa =>
        {
            spa.Options.SourcePath = "VueApp";

            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                spa.UseVueCliServer("serve");
            }
        });

        DbInitializer.Initialize(context, roleManager, userManager, env, loggerFactory);
    }
```

and the services...

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services
            .AddLogging(builder => builder
                .AddConsole()
                .AddDebug());

        services
            .AddMvc()
                .SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_1)
                .AddJsonOptions(options => options.SerializerSettings.ContractResolver = new CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver());

        // In production, the Vue files will be served from this directory
        services
            .AddSpaStaticFiles(configuration =>
            {
                configuration.RootPath = "wwwroot";
            });

        services
            .AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("MyConnection")))
            .AddIdentity<ApplicationUser, IdentityRole>(options =>
                {
                    // Password settings
                    options.Password.RequireDigit = true;
                    options.Password.RequiredLength = 8;
                    options.Password.RequireNonAlphanumeric = true;

                    // Lockout settings
                    options.Lockout.DefaultLockoutTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(30);
                    options.Lockout.MaxFailedAccessAttempts = 10;

                    // User settings
                    options.User.RequireUniqueEmail = true;
                })
            .AddRoleManager<RoleManager<IdentityRole>>()
            .AddSignInManager<SignInManager<ApplicationUser>>() // Not sure I need this - added to see if it made things better but it didn't
            .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>()
            .AddDefaultTokenProviders();

        services
            .ConfigureEntityServices()
            .ConfigureIdentityDependencies()
            .ConfigureDomainServices();

        services.AddAuthentication(options =>
        {
            options.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
            options.DefaultChallengeScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
            options.DefaultScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
        }).AddCookie(options =>
        {
            options.SlidingExpiration = true;
            options.Events.OnRedirectToLogin = cxt =>
            {
                cxt.Response.StatusCode = 401;
                return Task.CompletedTask;
            };
            options.Events.OnRedirectToAccessDenied = cxt =>
            {
                cxt.Response.StatusCode = 403;
                return Task.CompletedTask;
            };
            options.Events.OnRedirectToLogout = cxt => Task.CompletedTask;
        });
    }
```

I've also tried adding a Development only CORS policy to the Startup to allow anything in development mode to rule that out - It made no difference.

My log in method looks like this...

```
        public async Task<ActionResult<CurrentUserJsonModel>> LogIn(LoginJsonModel model)
    {
        if (model == null) return BadRequest();
        if (!ModelState.IsValid) return BadRequest(ModelState);

        var result = await authService.LogInAsync(model.UserName, model.Password);

        if (!result.Succeeded)
            return BadRequest(result.Errors.Select(e => new ErrorJsonModel(e)).ToArray());

        var principal = User;

        return new CurrentUserJsonModel
        {
            UserName = result.UserName,
            Roles = await authService.GetRolesAsync(model.UserName, model.Password)
        };
    }
```

TANGENT: (The var principal line was to test the current state while stepping through - While not null, User has not UserName or Claims in the Identity object when I step through after LogInAsync has been called (which I would think it should do at that point...).

Which calls an authService.LogInAsync method that looks like this...

```
        public async Task<AuthResult> LogInAsync(ApplicationUser user)
    {
        if (user != null)
        {
            await identityService.SignOutAsync();
            await identityService.SignInAsync(user);
        }

        return user != null
            ? new AuthResult(user)
            : new AuthResult("Password or Email address incorrect.");
    }
```

which uses identityService to wrap access to UserManager, SignInManager and RoleManager functions...

```
        public async Task SignInAsync(ApplicationUser user, bool isPersistent = true, string authenticationMethod = null)
        => await signInManager.SignInAsync(user, isPersistent, authenticationMethod);
```

When I load the app after having logged into the back end but having cleared the Vuex state (by refreshing the page) the app tries to call this method...

```
    [Authorize]
    [HttpGet]
    [ProducesResponseType(StatusCodes.Status401Unauthorized)]
    [ProducesResponseType(StatusCodes.Status403Forbidden)]
    public async Task<ActionResult<CurrentUserJsonModel>> Get()
    {
        if (HttpContextAccessor.HttpContext.User != null)
        {
            if (HttpContextAccessor.HttpContext.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
                return new CurrentUserJsonModel
                {
                    UserName = HttpContextAccessor.HttpContext.User.Identity.Name,
                    Roles = await authService.GetRolesAsync(HttpContextAccessor.HttpContext.User)
                };

            return Forbid();
        }

        return Unauthorized();
    }
```

When debugging the method isn't even stepped into - I'm getting a 401 thrown back at me on my browser console (which would make sense if Authorize was failing).

And for completeness, here's my vue.config.js

```
const baseUrl = ''

module.exports = {
    publicPath: baseUrl + '/',

    // place our built files into the parent project where they will be copied
    // into the distribution for deployment
    outputDir: '../wwwroot',

    filenameHashing: true, //process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production',
    lintOnSave: 'error',

    css: {
        modules: false,
        sourceMap: process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production',
        loaderOptions: {
            sass: {
                data: `
                    $fa-font-path: ${process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production' ? '"~/fonts"' : '"' + baseUrl + '/fonts"'};
                    @import "@/scss/base/index.scss";
                    @import "@/scss/helpers/index.scss";
                `
            }
        }
    },

    devServer: {
        host: 'localhost',
        port: 8080,
        hot: true,
        open: true,
        openPage: '',
        overlay: true,
        disableHostCheck: true,
        proxy: {
            // Proxy services to a backend API
            '/api': {
                target: process.env.PROXY || 'https://localhost:44368',
                secure: false,
                changeOrigin: true
            }
        }
    },

    // these node_modules use es6 so need transpiling for IE
    transpileDependencies: [
    ]
}
```

My console output in Visual Studio looks like this...

```
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost:Information: Request starting HTTP/1.1 GET http://localhost:44368/api/auth  
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker:Information: Route matched with {action = "Get", controller = "Auth"}. Executing action Ddm.Lcp.Iptn.Dashboard.Web.Api.AuthController.Get (Ddm.Lcp.Iptn.Dashboard.Web)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization.DefaultAuthorizationService:Information: Authorization failed.
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker:Information: Authorization failed for the request at filter 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Authorization.AuthorizeFilter'.
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ChallengeResult:Information: Executing ChallengeResult with authentication schemes ().
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Cookies.CookieAuthenticationHandler:Information: AuthenticationScheme: Cookies was challenged.
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker:Information: Executed action Ddm.Lcp.Iptn.Dashboard.Web.Api.AuthController.Get (Ddm.Lcp.Iptn.Dashboard.Web) in 10.8469ms
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost:Information: Request finished in 18.1495ms 401
```

This suggests that cookies are being challenged, as they should be given my set up - It does feel as if the actual sign in creation is not actually working.

The question is ... why is it failing?

**UPDATE:** According to @Kirk it may be related to a scheme mismatch between Cookies and Identity.Application. I have tested by commenting out the cookie elements in Startup and in this case I find myself in a recursive loop - I added the cookie elements to Startup.cs to enable me to get sensible responses from Authorization results.

I need to be able to do this but not get redirected to login pages which (In my app) do not exist and won't exist because it's an SPA.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`signInManager.SignInAsync(...)` uses the `Identity.Application` scheme, rather than the `Cookies` scheme that you've both registered and configured as the default. To use Identity and customise the cookie that it uses, use [`ConfigureApplicationCookie`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.dependencyinjection.identityservicecollectionextensions.configureapplicationcookie).

Replace the following:

```
services.AddAuthentication(options =>
{
    options.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
    options.DefaultChallengeScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
    options.DefaultScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
}).AddCookie(options =>
{
    options.SlidingExpiration = true;
    options.Events.OnRedirectToLogin = cxt =>
    {
        cxt.Response.StatusCode = 401;
        return Task.CompletedTask;
    };
    options.Events.OnRedirectToAccessDenied = cxt =>
    {
        cxt.Response.StatusCode = 403;
        return Task.CompletedTask;
    };
    options.Events.OnRedirectToLogout = cxt => Task.CompletedTask;
});
```

-with-:

```
services.ConfigureApplicationCookie(options =>
{
    options.SlidingExpiration = true;
    options.Events.OnRedirectToLogin = cxt =>
    {
        cxt.Response.StatusCode = 401;
        return Task.CompletedTask;
    };
    options.Events.OnRedirectToAccessDenied = cxt =>
    {
        cxt.Response.StatusCode = 403;
        return Task.CompletedTask;
    };
    options.Events.OnRedirectToLogout = cxt => Task.CompletedTask;
});
```