# signInManager.IsSignedIn return false but SignInAsync was called

Tags: c#, .net, oauth-2.0, authorization, microsoft-account

I'm try to add oAuth to my .net core application. I have that code in Startup.cs

```
 services
            .AddAuthentication( options =>
            {
                options.DefaultScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
                options.DefaultChallengeScheme = MicrosoftAccountDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
            } )
            .AddCookie()
            .AddMicrosoftAccount( microsoftOptions =>
            {
                microsoftOptions.ClientId = "...";
                microsoftOptions.ClientSecret = "...";
                microsoftOptions.SignInScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
            } );
```

And then in callback handler I try to authorize user like this

```
await _signInManager.SignInAsync( user, new AuthenticationProperties { IsPersistent = true, AllowRefresh = true } );
```

After that,  try to call **signInManager.IsSignedIn(HttpContext.User)** but it's return false.

I think problem in the signInManager, because his AuthorizationScheme use another cookie state or something like that

Comment: Found the post with same issue, but answer from there didn't help
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56398355/signinmanager-signinasync-doesnt-sign-me-in-vue-js-spa